# ESP8266 Upload hex file Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266

I am using ESP12E Wifi module, using library based on Arduino. Is there any way I can upload hex file of the project to esp8266 using Arduino or any tool?
I need to send hex file instead of code to my client. Is there any way?

Comment: Hex file of what?  A program built for the ESP8266, or a program built for a classic ATmega Arduino talking to it?  Either way, while you may be able to *obtain* a hex file, you probably can't *upload* it with the IDE without various hacks, but would need to use avrdude (for an ATmega) or some other tool (for an esp8266) directly.

Comment: Hex file of the code compiled in Arduino for esp8266

Comment: Hex file or binary file? Why can't you just use the Arduino IDE?  Esptool (https://github.com/themadinventor/esptool) should do what you want though, but finding out the correct arguments might take some effort.

Answer (score 2):

I see the main question you are asking is: "I need to send a hex file instead of code to my client. I want to keep my source code with me."

The mechanics of the final hardware solution aren't supplied but I will guess that your client is also using an Arduino or at least the same Atmel chip that you have in your Arduino, and will be using that chip to control the ESP8266.

When you build your sketch, there is a .hex file created that you can send to your client.

There are a few ways to keep the hex file around, and IDE 1.6.5 and up has a way to easily find this file:

Sketch > Export Compiled Binary
The sketch will compile.

Sketch > Show Sketch Folder
The .hex file will be in the sketch folder.

You can send this hex file to your customer.

If he is using an Arduino or ATMega-based solution to connect to the ESP8266, then the hex file can be loaded into his Arduino or to his Atmel chip. However, the Arduino IDE doesn't support *import* of hex files at this time.

Your client would have to load that hex file onto the Arduino with an ISP programmer of some sort. There are many ways to do this, and the best one for you will depend upon your circumstances and your client's skill set.

If the client is using an Arduino or has just embedded the same ATmel chip that is in your Arduino into his solution, you could also just program your Arduino, and then send him that chip.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on `Show verbose output during compilation` in your Arduino IDE and press `Verify`. After compile you can examine the parameters sent to `esptool.exe` in the last line before `Sketch uses...`. You will see some `.elf`, `.bin` and `.text` files. These are the files you want to send.